# Could not insert into table error in Java Hibernate MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pojo

In my project I get "could not insert the table error", I'm adding necesarry code parts to here and hope for the best :)

My LogIn Class

```
package DAO;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import tables.Users;


public class LogIn {

    Session session;

    public boolean RegisterUsers(Object user) {

        if (SaveDatabase(user)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean GetUsersWithId(Users user) {

        SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionfactory.openSession();

        user = (Users) session.get(Users.class, user.getUserId());
        session.close();
        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public boolean SaveDatabase(Object object) {
        try {

            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction transaction = null;
            Long courseId = null;
            try {
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(object);
                courseId = (Long) session.save(object);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

HibernateUtil

```
package DAO;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Test class for these codes

```
import DAO.LogIn;
import tables.Location;
import tables.Users;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Test RegisterUser and GetUsersWithId in here

    LogIn test = new LogIn();
    Users user = new Users();

    user.setUserEmail("email");
    user.setUserAdress("adres here");
    user.setUserFbId(3);
    test.RegisterUsers(user);

}
}
```

[image: Exact Error]

Thanks for help

Edit: Removed config. xml files and auto-created Users class to clean up the mess.

Comment: That is a huge amount of code. Is someone meant to debug it for you? Can you provide a [short example](http://sscce.org/), that is about 1/40th of the size, and generates the same error?

Comment: Can you please reduce the code to a minimal example and add an exact error message/stack trace?

Comment: Also, that's way too many variables for your Users class. You should refactor that out into other objects.

Comment: I tried my best to summerize the question.
Also Users is a database table and auto created via hibernate, that's why it has much variables on it.

Comment: session.save(object);
            courseId = (Long) session.save(object);
why do you do this twice? which line is it that fails?

Comment: Corrected the image and the lines that u mentioned, I commented it out and nothing have changed. It was one of my failed tries.

Comment: My comment on refactoring meant to include database tables.

Comment: are you sure before the save line, user is not null?

Comment: And which line is line 58?

Comment: To gil_bz, I checked what u said and my user class passes with no failure.
To Jesse J, line 58 is session.close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *field* named `session`, and a *local variable* also named `session`. You open a Hibernate session and assign it to the *local variable*, but you close the *field* and not the *local variable*.

Remove the `session` field. You shouldn't store a Hibernate Session in a field like that. It doesn't make sense. You'll then get a compilation error that you'll need to fix by declaring the session local variable in a larger scope (outside of the try block).

Comment: I've done what u said, thanks for the tip :)
Now insertion error become just "could not insert: [tables.Users]"
I meant that, null pointer exception has gone thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

Same field name is at global scope at class level and another is at local scope under SaveDatabase() method.

Solution: remove global scope session.

```
public class LogIn {
    Session session;    //Remove this field .....
```